# I have created a xamarin camera app ,i need help set the camera app a default camera u sing the manifest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, xamarin-studio

I have created a xamarin camera app, and I need help set the camera app a default camera using the manifest.

You can find the manifest code below, can you please help me to set the camera app as a default app.
how can I set the app as default app so that when I open a web app that uses the camera I can see it as one of the available to use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="MenikoCamera.Droid"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>


    <activity android:name="MenikoCamera.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Third party developers cannot set their own app as default applications. Only the users of your app can do this on their own devices.

You can however, register to receive intents of the types your app supports so that users can select your app as their default. For example, You always need a  <*category*> on an <*activity*> <*intent-filter*>, as there is always at least one category on the Intent used with startActivity().

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

For Camera

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: i have used my device to test,and removed the phone camera as default.and it can see other app and the cemara but my app is not showing

Comment: Use this Modified Code in above answer

Comment: where  do  I register to receive intents of the types my app supports